# Citation call-out, with hyperlink, to manually-input bibitem

Tags: hyperref, citing

I have manually created all entries in the bibliography section. Now, I would like to create authoryear-style citation call-outs and hyperlink the citation call-outs to the entries in the bilbiography.

Can someone help me to do this?

**I use the following packages:**

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

**An example of how I want it to look like**

```
\begin{document}

Text here (Author A, 2000)




\begin{thebibliography}


\bibitem{example} Author A (2000), Example 1



\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

**So: I want that I can click on ''(Author A, 2000)'' and then be redirected in the pdf to the Reference.**

Comment: Ŵelcome to TeX.SX! Your example misses (a lot of) features: `\documentclass` and a `\cite` command

Comment: You added some tags about `bibtex` and `cite-package`, but you use none of them in your code

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I've gone ahead and deleted some of the unneeded tags.

Comment: @Mico: That was actually a comment to the OP, pushing him to provide a better example ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I may be wrong, but I suspect the OP didn't know about the optional argument of `\bibitem` and how it might be used to form citation call-outs when issuing `\cite` instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve your objective, you should

- load the `natbib` package with the option `authoyear`,
- load the `hyperref` package, and
- use the optional argument of the `\bibitem` macro to provide the pieces of information that are needed to form the authoryear-style citation callouts. Note that there must not be a space between the author's name (or authors' names) and the year in the optional argument of `\bibitem`:

  ```
  \bibitem[Smith(2000)]{example} Smith, J. (2000), Example 1.
  ```

With such a setup, it's possible to use both the `\citep` and `\citet` macros of the `natbib` package.

A final remark: Just because it's possible to use this method doesn't mean it's *advisable* to do so. In the medium and long term, you'll do yourself a huge favor by learning how to use BibTeX and/or biblatex to handle the chores related to creating a formatted bibliography and generating appropriately formatted citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Text here  \citep{example}  % for parenthetic-style citation call-out

More text, \citet{example}  % for text-style citation call-out

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Smith(2000)]{example} Smith, J. (2000), Example 1.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, what if I want to have Smith et al. (2000)?

Comment: @student441 - Since you're manually formatting the bibliography, you must choose what you put in the optional arguments of the `\bibitem` macros. If you want "Smith et al. (2000)" in the citation call-out, you have to write `\bibitem[Smith et al.(2000)]{example}`. If you think this is tedious, I would fully agree with you. That's one reason why I wrote that you should look into learning how to use BibTeX and/or biblatex.

Comment: Ok thanks again! Very helpful. One more question:  \usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} makes also my equation links  (\eqref) blue instead of red. How can I make sure that my equation links stay red?

Comment: @student441 - Just reset the `citecolor` option to the color you like; e.g., write `citecolor=blue`. (The default color for citation callouts is light green, which I don't find all that appealing.) Depending on your color preferences, you may need to load the `xcolor` package as well, probably with one or more options. If you have a question about color choices, feel free to post a new question.