# Links to bibliography from main text in pdflatex

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, links

In my thesis, I am loading the `hyperref` package. The `thesis` package itself loads the `harvard` package. Here is the snippet of the relevant packages from my main `thesis.tex` file:

```
% dissertation style file
% loads the harvard package by default
\usepackage{unithesis} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}

% Use the first here for colored links in the PDF output file 
% use the second for printed output (black text only) 
% Note also that the setpagesize=false is necessary to stop 
% hyperref resetting the page size back to Letter
\hypersetup{setpagesize=false, a4paper=true, colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue,citecolor=black}
```

I am following the below notation in my .bib file. For example, to cite a journal article, I use:

```
@article {REF1, 
author = {Gassmann, Oliver and Zeschky, Marco},
title  = {{Opening up the Solution Space: The Role of Analogical Thinking for Breakthrough Product Innovation}}, 
journal = {Creativity and Innovation Management}, 
volume = {17}, 
number = {2}, 
publisher = {Blackwell Publishing Ltd}, 
issn = {1467-8691}, 
doi = {10.1111/j.1467-8691.2008.00475.x}, 
pages = {97--106}, 
year = {2008},
}
```

I want references from my main text to my bibliography. For instance, if I use `\cite{REF1}` in my main text, I should get a hyperlink to the above mentioned reference in my bibliography. That is not happening now. I googled for answers and also tried looking up previous posts, but could not find anything that resolved my problem. For instance, the following link discusses the same issue, but I could not figure out how to fix the issue from the answer:

[In Latex, how do I create citations to references with a hyperlink?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/In_Latex_how_do_I_create_citations_to_references_with_a_hyperlink)

Can anyone help me resolve this without loading any additional packages that would clash with the packages already loaded in my style sheet? I mention this because in another link related to the issue, the suggestion was to load the natbib package:

[Citation call-out, with hyperlink, to manually-input bibitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247575/citation-call-out-with-hyperlink-to-manually-input-bibitem)

But if load the natbib package, it messes my style sheet and I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \harvardurl already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. 
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

TIA for your suggestions.

Vinod

Comment: Does the problem persist if you don't load the `unithesis` package? if so, you should try and set up a mwe

Comment: @Davide If I do not load the unithesis package, it might work. The problem with this is that without loading this package, I would not be able to author my thesis, as it is the prescribed package for the uni.

Comment: Nobody of us knows package  unithesis` (very creative name by the way) nor your requirements for submitting a thesis. I would ask the maintainer of the package for advice and pointers.

Comment: Related: [hyperlinks and citations for specific template](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219323)